# beanio - To read data in order (Segment - Inner Segment)

Tags: java, xml, bean-io

**Code Snippet:**

```
<ce:title id="123"
    xmlns:ce="http://www..../dtd">Some sample content,
    <ce:ref refid="redif1" id="111">
        <ce:sup loc="post">*</ce:sup>
    </ce:ref>
    <ce:note id="id1">
        <ce:label>*</ce:label>
        <ce:para id="id123" view="all">Para Content,</ce:para>
    </ce:note>Continuation of some sample content.
</ce:title>
```

**Details:**

As per the above code snippet, I would like to extract the content in order.

**O/P Expected:**

```
Some sample content, * * Para Content, Continuation of some sample content.
```

Is there any way to extract the content as stated above from the XML provided.

Thanks in Advance

```
**XML Mapping:**

<segment name="header" xmlName="head" class="com.sample.Header" minOccurs="0">
    <field name="title" xmlName="title" xmlNamespace="http://www.../dtd" minOccurs="0"/>
    <segment name="titleModel" xmlName="title" xmlNamespace="http://www.../dtd" minOccurs="0" class="com.sample.TitleModel">
        <segment name="titleRef"  xmlName="ref" minOccurs="0" class="com.sample.TitleRef">
            <field name="superScript" xmlName="sup" minOccurs="0"/>
        </segment>
        <segment name="note" xmlName="note" class="com.sample.Note" minOccurs="0">
            <field name="label" xmlName="label" minOccurs="0"/>
            <field name="para" xmlName="para" minOccurs="0"/>
        </segment>
    </segment>
    .
    .
    .
    </segment>
```

Comment: There are many ways to extract the information you want. You have tagged it with BeanIO, is BeanIO the solution you want? If BeanIO, what have you tried so far? How does the mapping.xml or annotations look like? There are at least 3 other possible solutions from the top of my head, Mapping to JAXB to read the XML document, XPath expressions to find the values and you could even do it with regular expressions. So, please be more specific as to what your requirements are.

Comment: Hi, This is an existing implementation. Due to changes in the source XML am supposed to use Bean-IO. Hence am expecting the solution using Bean-io.

Comment: Please find the XML Mapping stated above.

Comment: <field name="title" xmlName="title" xmlNamespace="http://www.../dtd" minOccurs="0"/>

This mapping extracts "Some sample content," and "Continuation of some sample content." hence Before extracting the inner segments, both the contents are getting extracted and concatenated with the mapping. hence getting content in wrong order.

Comment: I have a bit of difficulty reproducing your code. I your mapping file you have `<segment name="header" xmlName="head" class="com.sample.Header" minOccurs="0">` but this element `head` is not shown on the input xml.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do it with bean-io, but if it's only the text content you're interessed in, you can use a simple SAX parser:

```
        SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/validation", false);
        SAXParser parser = factory.newSAXParser();
        parser.parse(new InputSource("input.xml"),
                new Handler(writer));
```

class Handler:

```
private static class Handler extends DefaultHandler {
    private final Writer out;

    private Handler(Writer out) {
        this.out = out;
    }

    @Override
    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
            throws SAXException {
        try {
            out.write(ch, start, length);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            throw new SAXException(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```